# Use if and else statement result as a variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Good Day everyone,

I need help in using the result of my if and else satement as a variable in the mysql query below:

```
SELECT type, description, IF(type = 'Fixed Assets', 'true', 'false') AS description, IF(description = description, 'true', 'false') AS description2 FROM table_name;
```

What I need is to use the result of 'description' as a condition in another column which is 'description2', so that I won't use the same IF and else statement of 'description 'over and over again.

The expected result for description is 'true', and the expected result for description2 is 'true' as well because the value for description = 'true'.

Any answers will be a good help, thank you.

Comment: `IF(description = description, ...)`? Are you expecting that to be not true?

Comment: You may need to `IF(IF(...))` to crack this nut.

Comment: Sorry I edited the query for the description2. It should be IF(description = description, 'true', 'false') AS description2

Comment: If `a=a`? This is going to be true for everything but `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat your `IF(type...)`:

```
select
    type,
    description,
    IF(type = 'Fixed Assets', 'true', 'false') AS description,
    IF(description = IF(type = 'Fixed Assets', 'true', 'false'), 'true', 'false') AS description2
```

Your other option is a subquery:

```
select type, description, is_fixed_assets, IF(description = is_fixed_assets, 'true', 'false') as description2
from (
    select type, description, IF(type = 'Fixed Assets', 'true', 'false') AS is_fixed_assets
    from table_name
) foo;
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing and it's not really looking good.